# Можно ли воспользоваться VTune на AMD FX 8350?

Tags: intel, amd

Я имею ввиду можно ли детектить им (`vtune amplifier 2015`) утечки памяти на этом процессоре?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Утечки памяти - гораздо более высокоуровневая проблема, от процессора теоретически не зависящая.